# javascript dynamically create an object and push to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, dynamic

I'm a little new to javascript and I have spent way too long on this.
I have two classes race and horse. I'm iterating through the array race.runners, where each entry is an object.

**Error Line**

```
result.push({ race.runners[i].number : c / race.runners[i].odds_dec }); //error line.
```

So key is a string (race number) and value is a number.
However, this gives me:

**Error**

',' expected synatx error.

**Code**

```
class horse {
  constructor(name, odds_dec, race, number) {
    this.number = number;
    this.name = name;
    this.odds_dec = odds_dec; //odds in decimal form.

  }
class race {
  constructor(runners) {
    this.runners = runners;
  }
//Runners will be an array storing horse objects.

function dropout(race, horse, budget) {

  c = budget / c;
  var result = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < race.runners.length; i++) {
    result.push({ race.runners[i].number : c / race.runners[i].odds_dec }); //error line.

  }
}

dropout(race, horse, budget);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use a value for dynamic keys, you need to wrap it in brackets:

```
for (var i = 0; i + race.runner.length; i++) {
  var runner = race.runners[i];
  var value = c / runner.odds_dec;
  result.push({ [runner.number]: value })
}
```

A little cleaner approach is using a for…of loop: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of

```
for (const runner of race.runner) {
  const value = c / runner.odds_dec;
  result.push({ [runner.number]: value })
}
```

The way I would do it is to use `.map`

```
const results = race.runner.map((runner) => {
  const value = c / runner.odds_dec;
  return { [runner.number]: value }
});
```

Also, don't forget to return your result!